# How do I resolve the error 'can't find module http'

Tags: typescript, webpack, ethereum, webpack-dev-server, web3js

I am working on a small Dapp with webpack and an UI based on web components (lit-library).
For bundling the files, I am using webpack and the webpack-dev-server to refresh the page. Everything works fine for me.

Now, I am trying to us web3 to interact with my smart contract, but when I import web3 and creating a new instance from this, I got the following error:

```
    Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'http'
    webpackMissingModule xml-http-request.js:21
    js xml-http-request.js:21
    Webpack 14
xml-http-request.js:21:19
    webpackMissingModule xml-http-request.js:21
    js xml-http-request.js:21
    Webpack 14
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        js
        __webpack_require__
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
        <anonymous>
```

This error appears in the console from my firefox.

### package.json

```js
{
  "name": "m-wallet-frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --open --mode=development",
    "dev": "webpack serve --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.36.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "lit": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "web3": "^1.3.5",
    "web3-providers-http": "^1.3.5"
  }
}
```

### webpack.config.json

```js
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin'); 

module.exports = {

    entry: {
      main: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "main.ts")
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      publicPath: "/dist/",
      clean: true
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        inject: true,
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html")
      }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        process: 'process/browser',
      }),
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: [
          path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
          path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        ],  
        compress: true,
        hot: false
      }
  };
```

According to the [web3-doc](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/getting-started.html#adding-web3-js) I use following import statemens:

```js
Import Web3 from 'web3';
let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");
```

After the first occurrence of the error I tried the node.js approach:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3')
let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");
```

Here is the [repository](https://github.com/KevvKo/wallet-app) without the web3 import.

I tried to install older version for web3 but it doesn't work for me.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you copy/paste how you are importing / using web3 in your code?

Comment: Sure. I updated the Post. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With webpack v5.x.x node-modules like http (which is required in web3) need a polyfill and a fallback to work. So, I added the following to my webpack.config.js:

```js
 const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    {...},
    resolve: {
      {...},
      fallback: {
        "http": require.resolve("stream-http")
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      {...},
      new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ],
  };
```

And install the following packages:

```
npm i -D stream-http
npm i -D node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
```

And the web3 import as above is working well.

Comment: cool! thanks for sharing. You can accept your own answer so this question will be marked as "solved".

Comment: Thanks.  That worked to me.  However, since I'm using Vue-cli, I had to make that changes in vue.config.js file.  https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html